# In fullcalendar v2, How can I set options dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

How can I set the `selectable` and `select` options after the calendar is created?

I tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('selectable', true);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', function(start, end) {
    ...
});
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

Docs: http://fullcalendar.io/docs

Answer (score 1):

@russell, i think u can't dynamically set the calendar properties once u initialize the fullCalendar.

may be u have to reinitialize the calendar by destroying previous instance.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
 InitializeCalendar(settings); //custom js method that will initialize calendar with settings.
```